# Spring не может установить зависимость

Tags: spring

При запуске приложения получаю ошибку:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'com.github.steed777.redsoft.redsoft.view.MainView':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'employeeAccountingEditor' defined in file [C:\MavenProject\redsoft\target\classes\com\github\steed777\redsoft\redsoft\components\EmployeeAccountingEditor.class]:
Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
Failed to instantiate [com.github.steed777.redsoft.redsoft.components.EmployeeAccountingEditor]:
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Property type 'java.lang.Long' doesn't match the field type 'java.lang.String'. Binding should be configured manually using converter.
```

Вот Editor:

```
@SpringComponent
@UIScope
public class EmployeeAccountingEditor extends VerticalLayout implements KeyNotifier {

    private final EmployeeRepository repository;
    private EmployeeAccounting accounting;

    private TextField fio = new TextField("","ФИО");
    private TextField pos = new TextField("","Должность");
    private TextField email = new TextField("","Электронная почта");
    private TextField phone = new TextField("","Телефон");
    private TextField salary = new TextField("","Зарплата");

    private Button save = new Button("Сохранить", VaadinIcon.CHECK.create());
    private Button cancel = new Button("Отменить");
    private Button delete = new Button("Удалить", VaadinIcon.TRASH.create());
    private HorizontalLayout actions = new HorizontalLayout(save, cancel, delete);

    private Binder<EmployeeAccounting> binder = new Binder<>(EmployeeAccounting.class);
    @Setter
    private ChangeHandler changeHandler;

    public interface ChangeHandler {
        void onChange();
    }

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeAccountingEditor(EmployeeRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;

        add(fio, pos, email, phone, salary, actions);
        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
        setSpacing(true);

        save.getElement().getThemeList().add("primary");
        delete.getElement().getThemeList().add("error");

        addKeyPressListener(Key.ENTER, e -> save());

        save.addClickListener(e -> save());
        delete.addClickListener(e -> delete());
        cancel.addClickListener(e -> editEmployee(accounting));
        setVisible(false);
    }

    private void delete() {
        repository.save(accounting);
        changeHandler.onChange();
    }

    private void save() {
        repository.delete(accounting);
        changeHandler.onChange();
    }

    public void editEmployee(EmployeeAccounting emp) {
        if (emp == null) {
            setVisible(false);
            return;
        } if (emp.getId() != null) {
            this.accounting = repository.findById(emp.getId()).orElse(emp);
        } else {
            accounting = emp;
        }

        binder.setBean(this.accounting);
        setVisible(true);

        fio.focus();
    }
}
```

А вот View:

```
@Route("")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final EmployeeRepository repository;
    private final Grid<EmployeeAccounting> grid;

    private final TextField filter;
    private final Button addNewBtn;
    private final EmployeeAccountingEditor editor;

    @Autowired
    public MainView(EmployeeRepository repository, EmployeeAccountingEditor editor){
    this.repository = repository;
    this.grid = new Grid<>(EmployeeAccounting.class);
    this.editor = editor;
    this.filter = new TextField();
    this.addNewBtn = new Button("Новый сотрудник", VaadinIcon.PLUS.create());

    HorizontalLayout action = new HorizontalLayout(filter, addNewBtn);

    filter.setPlaceholder("Поиск");
    filter.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.EAGER);
    filter.addValueChangeListener(e -> listEmployees(e.getValue()));

    add(action, grid, editor);

    grid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(e -> {
        editor.editEmployee(e.getValue());
    });

    addNewBtn.addClickListener(e -> editor.editEmployee(new EmployeeAccounting()));

    editor.setChangeHandler(() -> {
        editor.setVisible(false);
        listEmployees(filter.getValue());
    });

    listEmployees("");
}

private void listEmployees(String name) {
    if(name.isEmpty()) {
        grid.setItems(this.repository.findAll());
    } else {
        grid.setItems(this.repository.findByName(name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Связано с тем что используется:

```
private TextField phone = new TextField("","Телефон");
private TextField salary = new TextField("","Зарплата");
```

Для типа данных `Long`.